# file cannot be delete from asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hello guys I a webproject in asp.net my project worked fine in my pc but after uploading it to a iis server it is not working.
My webproject is to delete a file,

```
string s;
    int i;
    s = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp"); ;

            string[] prefetchtlist = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*");

                for (i = 0; i < prefetchtlist.Length; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(prefetchtlist[i]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }


    Label1.Text = "Completed";
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should post relevant source code so we can actually help you with your problem, since your current question lacks enough critical information to help us resolve your problem.

Comment: @user: edit your question to include the code that performs the deletion. Be sure to include any errors and their exact wording.

Comment: Please put the error text in too.

Comment: I doesn't get any error but the files remain as it is.

Comment: I wonder if it's because you're swallowing the exception...

Comment: no dude but it works fine on my pc

Comment: You're swallowing the exception. You'll never see the error on the server side with code like this!

Answer (score 1):

The file may not delete for a variety of reasons. Remove the `try`/`catch` block and see what exception is displayed by your web server.

Also, if an exception is caught, the next file in your array will be skipped because you have `i++` in the `catch` block - you don't need that there because `i` will just get incremented again when execution returns to the top of the `for` loop.